# How to change color of icon in Editable Svg Icons system in vuejs cookbook?

Tags: css, svg, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use the system proposed by vuejs cookbook for keeping svg icons (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/editable-svg-icons.html)

So I have 2 components: IconBase and IconArrowUp. I need to change color of arrow icon on hover (also css transition should be applied).

In the article they have `iconColor` property. But I didn't manage to change the color using css, and it's not that convenient to use events like onmouseenter.

Here is the code of two components:

IconBase.vue:

```
<template>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       :width="width"
       :height="height"
       viewBox="0 0 100 100"
       role="presentation"
       @click="$emit('click')">
    <g :fill="iconColor">
      <slot />
    </g>
  </svg>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      width: {
        type: [Number, String],
        default: 18
      },
      height: {
        type: [Number, String],
        default: 18
      },
      iconColor: {
        type: String,
        default: 'currentColor'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And IconArrowUp.vue:

```
<template>
  <path d="m12.398 40.102 13.402 13.5 14.699-14.801v58.699h19v-58.699l14.699 14.801 13.402-13.5-37.602-37.602z"/>
</template>
```

So this is how I use them (another component ScrollToTop.vue):

```
<template>
  <div class="scroll-to-top">
    <icon-base class="icon-arrow-up"
               width="20"
               height="20"
               icon-color="#949494">
      <icon-arrow-up/>
    </icon-base>
  </div>
</template>
```

How can I change to color of icon on hover? I want to keep `IconArrowUp` component clean though, so that if I need I use it without color change

Answer (score 4):

If the hover color is always the same, you could simply use the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) psuedo-class. For example, this CSS makes the icon blue when the SVG container is hovered, and the transition takes 400ms:

```html
<style scoped>
  /* <g class="icon" ...> */
  .icon {
    transition: fill .4s ease;
  }
  svg:hover .icon {
    fill: blue;
  }
</style>
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/k1mw5ll8no)

Otherwise, if the hover color is dynamic, you'd use JavaScript. You could make the `fill` conditional on a local Boolean that changes based on `mouseover`/`mouseout` events:

1. In `IconBase.vue`, define a local data variable (e.g., named `isHover`) to track the hover state, and a `prop` to set the color during the hover state:

```js
props: [
  // ...
  iconHoverColor: {
    type: String,
    default: "currentColor"
  }
],
data() {
  return {
    isHover: false
  }
}
```

2. Edit `IconBase.vue`'s template to make `fill` conditional on `isHover`, and set `isHover` based on the SVG container's `mouseover`/`mouseout` events:

```html
<svg @mouseover="isHover=true" @mouseout="isHover=false">
  <g :fill="isHover ? iconHoverColor : iconColor">
```

3. To set the color transition, use the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) CSS property on a class applied to `<g>`:

```html
<style scoped>
  /* <g class="icon" ...> */
  .icon {
    transition: fill .4s ease;
  }
</style>
```

4. In `ScrollToTop.vue`, edit the usage of `IconBase` to set the hover color:

```html
<icon-base icon-hover-color="#ff0000" ...>
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/l4p9kr27jz)